# Adding multiple endpoint routes to .net core console app from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-core-3.1

I'm using .net core 3.1 to build a console app that acts as an event handler API.

The app captures changes to a database and directs those changes to other APIs, in real-time. Updates to "customer" go to "customerAPI", "product" goes to "productAPI" and so on. This means that I have an appsettings.Local.json that looks like this:

```
 "DBConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "AccountEndpoint=(my account)",
    "SourceDatabaseName": "MyDB",
    "SourceContainerName": "MySource",
    "LeasesContainerName": "MyLease",
    "PartitionKey": "/id"
  },
  "EndpointAPIStrings": {
    "Endpoint1": {
      "EndpointUrl": "https://localhost:7777",
      "Username": "myusername1",
      "Password": "mypassword1",
    "Endpoint2": {
      "EndpointUrl": "https://localhost:8888",
      "Username": "myusername2",
      "Password": "mypassword2",
    "Endpoint3": {
      "EndpointUrl": "https://localhost:9999",
      "Username": "myusername3",
      "Password": "mypassword3"
    ...
    }
```

I am currently using a crappy method of declaring them as EnvironmentVariables to get them from my Main where the configuration is built to my CallAPI Task.

Main:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    IConfiguration configuration = BuildConfiguration(environmentName);
    CosmosClient cosmosClient = BuildCosmosClient(configuration);

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("EndpointUrl", configuration["EndpointAPIStrings:Endpoint1:EndpointURL"]);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Username", configuration["EndpointAPIStrings:Endpoint1:Username"]);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Password", configuration["EndpointAPIStrings:Endpoint1:Password"]);
    ...
}
```

Delegate function:

```
...
if (entityType == "myproduct")
{
    var entity = "products";
    var result = await Task.Run(() => CallAPIAsync(entity, item));
}
...
```

Task CallAPI:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPIAsync(string entity, ProcessedItem item)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var endpointUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EndpointUrl");
        var uri = new Uri($"{endpointUrl}/api/{entity}/{item.Id}/propagate");
        string username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Username");
        string password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Password");
        ...
    }
}
```

This obviously only works for the first endpoint and ignores the others.

**How can I refactor this to get the values into my CallAPI Task for all EndpointAPIStrings?**

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in a Windows Service .net Core 3.1 app, pretty similar. Essentially when you call your IHostBuilder function in program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureLogging(loggerFactory => loggerFactory.AddEventLog())
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
```

You get access to your configuration variables from appsettings.json by default. Which can then be accessed in your main startup or execute function:

```
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IConfiguration config)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
                _config = config;
            }
```

And then in your main or execute function:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            // Must be a scoped process in order to run correctly
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            // Start timer and begin log
            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var env = _config.GetValue<string>("ENV");
            var stageTable = _config.GetValue<string>("StageTable");
            var prevTable = _config.GetValue<string>("PrevTable");
            var mainTable = _config.GetValue<string>("MainTable");
            var sqlConnectionString = _config.GetValue<string>("SqlConnString_" + env);
            var excelConnectionString = _config.GetValue<string>("ExcelConnectionString1") +
                                        _config.GetValue<string>("ExcelFilePath_" + env) +
                                        _config.GetValue<string>("ExcelFileName") +
                                        _config.GetValue<string>("ExcelConnectionString2");
```

With an appsettings.json like:

```
"ENV": "LOCAL",
"StageTable": "Staging",
"PrevTable": "Previous",
"MainTable": "Courses",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for it and read the values into that class. Also changing it to a list in the JSON would be good. Steps I would do:

1. Change 'EndpointAPIStrings' into an array:

   ```
   {
     "EndpointAPIStrings":[
       {
          "Id":"Endpoint1",
          "EndpointUrl":"https://localhost:7777",
          "Username":"myusername1",
          "Password":"mypassword1"
       },
       {
          "Id":"Endpoint2",
          "EndpointUrl":"https://localhost:8888",
          "Username":"myusername2",
          "Password":"mypassword2"
       },
       {
          "Id":"Endpoint3",
          "EndpointUrl":"https://localhost:9999",
          "Username":"myusername3",
          "Password":"mypassword3"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Create a C# class defining the objects in the JSON array:

   ```
   public sealed class EndPoint {
       public string Id { get; set; }

       public string EndPointUrl { get; set; }

       public string Username { get; set; }

       public string Password { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Change data retrieval from the configuration:

   ```
   IConfiguration configuration = BuildConfiguration(environmentName);
   CosmosClient cosmosClient = BuildCosmosClient(configuration);

   List<EndPoint> endPoints = configuration.GetSection("EndPointAPIStrings").Get<List<EndPoint>>();
   ```

---

Now you have all your endpoints in the `endPoints` variable. You can remove and add properties into the JSON how you like and the only thing you need to do is change the class accordingly. **Please note** that you need the same names in the JSON and in the C# class in order to get a successful mapping.

Comment: Thanks, this populates the list in Main. How do I use the values in my task? It doesn't seem like I can pass them as parameters, since I am calling tasks from other tasks.

Comment: You can set them in your main class as a static list (I wouldn't advise that). You can still save them as environment variables (like right now) just use JsonConvert to serialize and deserialize from/to string and the list.